# Is it possible to load a variable from a JS script in another HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a JS script inside a HTML file that get a certain value from API and put on a variable. I want to put that same variable with the value on another HTML file (The new HTML file is loaded from a button in the previous page). Is there any way to to that?

Comment: Try out sessionStorage: `sessionStorage.setItem('key', variable);` will store the variable value in the browser session storage. `sessionStorage.getItem('key');` will return the set value of said variable. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: You could maybe get away with assigning it to `window`? Not sure how viable that is, though. Take with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two easy ways.

1.) Try out sessionStorage: `sessionStorage.setItem('key', variable);` will store the variable value in the browser session storage. `sessionStorage.getItem('key');` will return the set value of said variable.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

2.) Add the variable value to your url `www.yourdomain.com?key=value` and retrieve it from your second script.

```
const urlString = window.location.href;
const url = new URL(urlString);
const value = url.searchParams.get("key");
```

See: [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: Used the first way and worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!